Where in the works of Maimonides does he address how to deal with apparent contradictions between halakha and empirical facts?
Maimonides’ view is that halakha is teleological (see for example Guide III, 27,31) e.g. some laws are to promote societal wellbeing, correct moral beliefs, etc. Where in his works does he deal with how to handle a demonstration on the basis of empirical fact that a particular law promotes suffering or where he explains how such a demonstration is impossible or irrelevant? I am simply looking for references to Maimonides’ works which are relevant.
I am not asking how to deal with contradictions between aggadata and empirical facts.
I would also be interested in places in Maimonides’ works where he deals with how to deal with a demonstration that the halakha is not the most effective way to realize the purpose of the law, but some other law is or where he explains how such a demonstration is impossible, or irrelevant.

Does this answer your question? Rambam on the Gemara's Scientific and Historical authenticity

@Kazibácsi thanks for this. It is related to what I asked about rabbinic statements, but does not address what I’ve asked about contradictions with the law.

@Kazibácsi I think between Guide II,25 and the introduction to Helek, it mostly answers the second part of my question by saying to interpret things allegorically. I will edit the question so it only pertains to the first part of my question regarding contradictions with the law. Thank you. Any other sources on the second part would be appreciated though.

"Maimonides’ view is that halakha is teleological e.g. some laws are to promote societal wellbeing, correct moral beliefs, etc." When making claims, please try to support them with proper reference/citation.

The meaning of "teleology": See 1 Kings 5:12, Isaiah 40:26 and also Job 19:25-27.

@YaacovDeane. No. That term is mine (really from one of Maimonides’ primary influences: Aristotle) intended as synonymous for when Maimonides discusses the “purpose” or “aim” of the law as in “[t]he Law as a whole aims at two things: the welfare of the soul and the welfare of the body …” (Guide III, 27).

Could you bring an example a law that promotes suffering? I'm not aware any of them, especially from a Jewish perspective.

@Kazibácsi. It’s a question about a conceivable, hypothetical situation. Maybe there are examples but it’s besides the point. I’m just asking if / where Maimonides addresses this point.

@GUT Take a look at the root word in English as found in Merriam Webster’s English Dictionary for example. Definitions 1-3 and then look at the sources from Tanach cited in my comment. Rambam speaks in the language and word usage of the Tanach. Rambam’s primary influence is what he was taught by his father.

The quote in this answer may be relevant.

"or where he explains how such a demonstration is impossible or irrelevant?" Not sure if this is helpful but in MN 3:26 he discusses how there are details of the law that have no underlying object and it is impossible for it to be otherwise.

The Rambam is always careful to distinguish between knowledge of facts and knowledge of good and evil (More Nevuchim 1:2). A law can never contradict the fact that it causes suffering. The fact that a law causes suffering could only contradict a claim that a law doesn't cause suffering.
The Rambam says that all the commandments have a purpose, but having a purpose doesn't mean that they don't cause suffering. Sometimes the suffering of the individual is outweighed by the benefit to the majority. For example, we put criminals to death, causing them suffering, to prevent crime, which damages the rest of society (1:54, 3:34).
Finally, we don't know the reason for the commandments, because the Torah itself doesn't give them. If we are able to somehow measure the benefit and detriment of the commandments towards attaining particular goals, we still can't say that the benefit of a commandment is outweighed by the suffering it causes, because it's our own problem for not understanding the real reason (3:26).

@b a thank you for your response. Regarding Guide I,2, I think I see where Rambam distinguishes between true/false and fine/bad (a kind of positive/normative distinction). Is the suggestion that empirical facts cannot bear on normative facts? I guess I'm having difficulty since in my mind, whether or not a law promotes e.g. "welfare of the body" is an empirical question ... It's hard for me to see how Rambam can maintain that law cannot be evaluated empirically given his teleological view.

@b a regarding Guide III,26, Rambam explicitly states that the reasons for the commandments are knowable and should be understood. Here is one illustrative passage. Regarding a comment in Bereshit Rabba he says: "[t]hough this dictum is very strange and has no parallel in their other dicta, I have interpreted it, as you will hear, in such a manner that we shall not abandon the views of all their dicta and we shall not disagree with a universally agreed upon principle, namely, that one should seek in all the Laws an end that is useful in regard to being: For it is no vain thing" (III,26).

@GUT "I'm having difficulty since in my mind, whether or not a law promotes e.g. "welfare of the body" is an empirical question. It's hard for me to see how Rambam can maintain that law cannot be evaluated empirically given his teleological view." I think such an occasion would give rise to re-assessing whether one was accurate in ascertaining the rationale for the law, not whether the law is correct. Though one ought seek a useful end in the law, there is no absolute guarantee that one has arrived at the correct conclusion. It is a valuable but ultimately speculative project.

@GUT Regarding 1:2: Empirical facts certainly bear on normative facts, but each of them has to be understood in its own way. Whether something is good is an empirical question if good is defined in rational terms (as in 3:10). So yes, if you rigorously define what's good for the body (as in "health" in 3:10), and you know what effect two laws have on the body, you can compare them with respect to that effect. But contradiction only arises after you translated the normative fact into an empirical fact, and this translation has limitations which have to be taken into account.

On 3:26: Yes, the reasons for the commandments are knowable, but the Torah doesn't say what they are, hence the possibility of error on our part (along the lines of @Deuteronomy). "'It is not in vain, and if it is in vain, it is only so through you.' That is to say, the giving of these commandments is not a vain thing and without any useful object; and if it appears so to you in any commandment, it is owing to the deficiency in your comprehension" (and next sentences) i.e. the commandments have reasons, but people are also liable to misunderstand them which is why the reasons were concealed.

@Deuteronomy. Yes. I think that's a reasonable thing to say. However, it's a bit hard to reconcile with what Maimonides says at the end of III,26: "I have seen fit to divide the six hundred and thirteen commandments into a number of classes ... I shall inform you of the cause of every one of these classes, and I shall show their utility about which there can be no doubt and to which there can be no objection". You can see Twersky's Introduction to the Code of Maimonides section VI (p. 401) for a more nuanced discussion / sources.

@GUT "about which there can be no doubt and to which there can be no objection" refers to the fact of their utility... not necessarily to his particular conclusion about what that utility consists of. Absolute certitude is not how Maimonideans, including his own son, understand this. See Twersky on p. 403 and fn. 122.

@Deuteronomy. Thank you for pointing out my error. This instead is an illustrative passage “you will hear my explanation for all of them and my exposition of the correct and demonstrated causes for them all with the sole exception - as I have mentioned to you - of details and particular commandments” (III, 28). Yes I’m aware of those who insisted on the “relative nature of the explanations” (Twersky). That’s what I meant by a more nuanced discussion. I think you would need textual evidence to support “absolute certitude is not how …”. If you have such evidence in Maimonides, I am interested.

@GUT The ellipses leaving out "Maimonideans" in the quote from me is significant. Clearly this is a matter of interpretation that emerges from some ambiguity, with those with a direct mesorah from the Rambam clarifying his intent. The anti-Maimonideans preferred to turn it into a "gotcha" moment.

@Deuteronomy. I used the ellipses because of the character limit actually. I’m not sure I see what the significance is. I’m also not seeing the ambiguity, nor am I seeing how there is any “gotcha” moment. Perhaps you could explain? To create such an ambiguity, I think you’d need evidence from what Maimonides writes. Like I said, if you have such evidence I am interested. I think the passage I quoted is quite unambiguous. He explicitly refers to “correct and demonstrated causes” of the laws. I don’t see how it could be more clear.

@GUT The ellipses as used seems to imply the statement devolves upon Maimonides, rather than Maimonideans (which is how I deliberately chose to phrase it). I'm not sure how you fail to see the ambiguity if you've gone over the sources and as you note have read some secondary literature on the topic (Twersky). "Correct and demonstrated causes" must be read in the larger context (which there simply isn't room to get into in a comments section (nor is it the place to). As for not seeing it as a "gotcha" moment, then you ignore the historic context of who made the criticisms.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
